# SQL subquery Joinwith three tables

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

[image: table schema]
I want to sql subquery to have 3 tables well of information, unfortunately I have this error

> Column does not belong to referenced table.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -206.
>   Column unknown.
>   NOM_CLIENT.
>   At line 7, column 12.

```
`select
           f.fact_n,
           f.fact_dos_n,
           poste_facture,
           montant_produits,
           date_ouverture_dos,
           nom_client,
           adresse_client
        from factures   f
            left outer join
          --detail facture par poste facturation
            ( select
            facture_detail.fact_n,
            facture_detail.factd_poste_fact as poste_facture,
            sum(facture_detail.factd_produits) as montant_produits
            from facture_detail
            GROUP BY facture_detail.fact_n,facture_detail.factd_poste_fact
           )fact_d on (f.fact_n = fact_d.fact_n )
          --information client  et dossier
          left outer join
          --debut niveau dossier
            (select
            dos.dos_n as dos_n,
            dos.dos_date_ouvr as date_ouverture_dos
            from dossiers dos
            left outer join
            --debut niveau client
                     (select
                     cl.cl_n ,
                     cl.cl_nom as nom_client,
                     cl.cl_adresse as adresse_client
                     from clients cl
                     --fin niveau client
                     )cl on(dos.dos_cl_n=cl.cl_n)
            --fin niveau dossier
            )dos on (f.fact_dos_n =  dos.dos_n )
    --fin niveau facture
              where f.fact_n=:AFACT_N`
```

Comment: i think you forgot to give alias to `nom_client` column name. is that column present in `factures   f`  table

Comment: you didn't select nom_client in select ... from dossiers dos, ooh you gave same alias name to "dossiers dos" and subquery (...) dos

Comment: fact_n and fact_dos_n in table facture ,  dos.dos_n and dos.dos_cl_n  in table dossiers    ,  cl.cl_n ans  cl_nom present in table client     f.fact_dos_n=dos.dos_n    dos.dos_cl_n =cl.cl_n

Comment: change the aliases for tables, you can't use 'dos' twice

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
select
           f.fact_n,
           f.fact_dos_n,
           poste_facture,
           montant_produits,
           date_ouverture_dos,
           nom_client,
           adresse_client
        from factures   f
            left outer join
          --detail facture par poste facturation
            ( select
            fd.fact_n,
            fd.factd_poste_fact as poste_facture,
            sum(fd.factd_produits) as montant_produits
            from facture_detail fd
            GROUP BY fd.fact_n,fd.factd_poste_fact
           )fact_d on (f.fact_n = fact_d.fact_n )
          --information client  et dossier
          left outer join
          --debut niveau dossier
            (select
            dos.dos_cl_n as dos_cl_n
            dos.dos_n as dos_n,
            dos.dos_date_ouvr as date_ouverture_dos
            from dossiers dos
            left outer join
            --debut niveau client
                     (select
                     cl.cl_n ,
                     cl.cl_nom as nom_client,
                     cl.cl_adresse as adresse_client
                     from clients cl
                     --fin niveau client
                     )cl on(dos.dos_cl_n=cl.cl_n)
            --fin niveau dossier
            )dos1 on (f.fact_dos_n =  dos1.dos_n )
    --fin niveau facture
              where f.fact_n=:AFACT_N
```

Comment: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 24, column 13.
dos.        ""dos.dos_n as dos_n,""

Comment: i add "comma" before  the same thing "  Column unknown.
NOM_CLIENT.
At line 7, column 12. "

Answer (score 0):

You Should You `inner join` instead `left outer join`

```
      select
           f.fact_n,
           f.fact_dos_n,
           poste_facture,
           montant_produits,
           date_ouverture_dos,
           nom_client,
           adresse_client,
           fd.fact_n,
           fd.factd_poste_fact as poste_facture,
           sum(fd.factd_produits) as montant_produits,
           dos.dos_n as dos_n,
           dos.dos_date_ouvr as date_ouverture_dos,
           cl.cl_n ,
           cl.cl_nom as nom_client,
           cl.cl_adresse as adresse_client
        from factures   f
        inner join  facture_detail fd
             on f.fact_n = fd.fact_n
        inner join dossiers dos
             on f.fact_dos_n =  dos.dos_n 
        inner join clients cl
             on dos.dos_cl_n=cl.cl_n
        where f.fact_n=:AFACT_N
            GROUP BY 
           fd.fact_n,fd.factd_poste_fact
```

**Note:**

> `Inner join` produces only the set of records that match in both Table A and Table B.
>
> `Left outer join` produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no match, the right side will contain null.

**INNER JOIN [image: INNER JOIN]**

**LEFT OUT JOIN [image: LEFT OUT JOIN]**

Comment: Column unknown.
POSTE_FACTURE.
At line 4, column 12.             montant_produits= sum(facture_detail.factd_produits) as montant_produits,